# How do I have text hover over a custom shape?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script>
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(82, 77, 76,0.5)';
    ctx.fillRect(15, 135, 720, 600);
</script>

<html>
    <body>
        <div Id = "text">
           <ul>
              <li>example1 </li>
              <li> example 2</li>
           </ul>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<style>
    .text [Z-index: 1;]
</style>
```

So I want this little text list to be on top of my custom simple rectangle shape but it just doesn't go on top! What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS you are selecting .text when you should really be selecting #text, since it's an ID. You're also using brackets ( [ ] ) instead of curly braces ( { } ) in your CSS.

Also, it should be

```
<div id="text">
```

Since you don't want to capitalize 'id'.

Comment: Oh no i typed it out on the phone to ask the question and my phones keyboard doesn't have {} so i couldn't put it in and i did not capitalize the id, its my phones auto correct.

Comment: No problem, you're still selecting the wrong thing in your CSS, which appears to be your issue.

Comment: I just figured it out, It turns out that I had to set the text position to absolute in the HTML file this whole time. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
 <html>
    <div style="position: absolute">
`<div id = "text">
<ul> 
    <li>example1</li>
    <li>example2</li>
     </ul>
</div>
</div>
</html>
```

It's actually quite simple. All you have to do is have another div wrapping the html code indicating that the position is absolute. Doesn't work on CSS for some reason but this HTML will do.